# Xcode .CalendarUnitDay doesn't exist

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, calendar

This may be a problem with my xCode or something, but I'm using some code to get the current date and I keep getting an error on this line of code,

```
var comp = cal.components((.CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMin), fromDate: date);
```

This is all the code

```
    var date = NSDate();
    var cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar();
    let comps : NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour;
    var info = cal.components(comps, fromDate: date);

    var day = info.day;
    var hour = info.hour;
    var min = info.minute;

    var text = "Day:  + \(day) + \nHour:  + \(hour) + \nMinute:  + \(min)";
    label.text = text;
```

telling me that the .CalendarUnitDay and .CalendarUnitMin are not member variables. This may be some silly error on my end but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong, nor have I been able to find a solution in Apple's doc, or Online. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, i did import Foundation

Comment: Your new code works fine for me. What crashes at your end? Perhaps you have no `label`. But, as I said before, that's a completely different issue.

Comment: error with breakpoints came up, i apologize for the misunderstanding. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it in two lines. First form the bitmask:

```
let comps : NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitDay
```

Now *use* `comps` where the components are needed:

```
var comp = cal.components(comps, fromDate: date)
```

Also, make sure you have unwrapped `cal`. It arrives as an Optional, so you must unwrap it. For example:

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
```

Notice the exclamation mark at the end.

So, put them all together with an arbitrary date:

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let date = NSDate()
let comps : NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitDay
var comp = cal.components(comps, fromDate: date)
```

Comment: This works, it is odd to me hour .CalendarUnit<unit> doesn't seem to change color.

Comment: nevermind, this crashes. This is the line that causes the crash       var comp = cal.components(comps, fromDate: date)

Comment: It doesn't crash. I've combined the lines to show an actual piece of code. It works fine. - I've shown you my code, you have not shown me yours, so I have no way of knowing what _else_ you may be doing wrong. But my answer is correct.

Comment: Allow me to apologize, I understand it doesn't crash for you, however, I am having some issues. Unfortunately I'm kinda struggling to format my code in this comment.

Comment: Update your _question_. Don't try to show code in the comment, it's darned near impossible. - However, the question here is whether _my_ code crashes for you. If not, I have answered _your_ question. If you have further difficulties, ask a _new_ question, since the issue must be a different one.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `.CalendarUnitDay` by `NSCalendarUnit.Day`
and `.CalendarUnitMin` by `NSCalendarUnit.Minute`.